# Using a module that turns the output of Findroot into a function of a variable

Tags: equation-solving, scoping

I am trying to create a module that finds the root `b*` of some equation with two variables `b` and `v` and that expresses that solution as a function of `v`, but I am having problems.

A simplified version of my problem which I can solve without the use of a module is the following.

```
zero:=$MachineEpsilon
IMPU[b_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate [(y - b), {y, b, v}];
IMPD[b_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate [(b - y), {y, zero, b}];
bFP[v_?NumericQ, \[Lambda]_?NumericQ] := 
  Re[t] /. FindRoot[
     IMPU[t, v] == \[Lambda]*IMPD[t, v], {t, zero, v}][[1]];
Plot[bFP[v, 1], {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

`IMPU[b,v]` and `IMPD[b,v]` are parts the equation `IMPU[b,v]=\[Lambda]*IMPD[b,v]` that needs to be solved in `b` with FindRoot (`\[Lambda]` is a positive parameter).
The solution `b` for a given `v` gives the function `bFP[v,\[Lambda]]`.

I would like to create a module for `bFP[v,\[Lambda]]` that hopefully speeds up the estimation of more sophisticated specifications. So I tried to define `bFP[\[Lambda]][v]` as follows but it does not work:

```
bFP[\[Lambda]_?NumericQ] := Module[{b, v},
   b[v]= t /. 
     FindRoot[
       NIntegrate [(y - b), {y, b, v}] == \[Lambda]*
         NIntegrate [(b - y), {y, zero, b}], {b, zero, v}][[1]]];
```

The error messages i get is:

```
FindRoot::srect: Value v$2075590 in search specification {t,zero,v$2075590} is not a number or array of numbers.
ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[NIntegrate[y-t,{y,t,v$2075590}]==1 NIntegrate[t-y,{y,zero,t}],{t,zero,v$2075590}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
...
General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation.
ReplaceAll::argx: ReplaceAll called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.
```

I suppose that something in Line 2 or else is wrong but I still cannot figure out what from the previous entries on the topic. Any thoughts?

Comment: NIntegrate needs numeric values, not symbolic.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Yes you are right, and this is what I am having trouble with. I have tried to define the module as ```bFP[v_?NumericQ, \[Lambda]_?NumericQ]``` and do not do not get the error messages anymore... but I still cannot get the solution to FindRoot to be expressed as a function of ```v```. Would you have any suggestion for how to achieve this, or any hint in this regard?

Comment: MMA version 13.3. I do get a plot now, a straight line from {0,0} to {1,0.5}

Comment: I am running 12.3 but I think it is more a basic syntax problem that I am having so the version shouldn't matter much, or does it? Can you please post the code you used to get the (correct) straight line? That would already help a lot.

Comment: It is your code, copied from here. The plot I get is from the line: `Plot[bFP[v, 1], {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}] `

Comment: I now run version 13.2 and my code with the module (without any change) but I still get the error message, which is not surprising! The only way to produce a plot with this code is if I first run the code lines without the module and then ```Plot[bFP[v, 1], {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]```... but this obviously bypasses the code lines with the module!

Comment: Have you tried a new kernel?

Comment: Sorry I don't get how trying a new kernel would solve my module problem or allow me to produce a plot with the code I wrote. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Often some unwanted or unnoticed declaration is made that creates bizarre behavior.

Comment: Hey Daniel my command of Mathematica is pretty limited and I'm willing to learn but I'm still unclear what I is wrong with my code :) Is it correct but I need to do something about declaring kernels (and if so what), or is it incorrect?

Comment: I think I finally see what's wrong. I overread the equal sign in ` IMPU[t, v] == \[Lambda]*IMPD[t, v]`. FindRoot needs a numerical expression, not a boolean expression. It should actually give an error message. Why it works in the first case I can not just say, I need  time to investigate.

Comment: But IMPU and IMPD are numerical expressions, no?

Comment: Yes, but  ` IMPU[t, v] == [Lambda]*IMPD[t, v]` is a boolean expression.